# how to check "contains" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I tried of checking contains option using jquery for the birthday but its getting exception

```
var _dob = "4/10";
// this line doesn't work
var _adob = _dob.contains('/') ? _dob.Split('/') : _dob.Split('-');
$('#Month').val(_adob[0]);
$('#Day').val(_adob[1]);
```

but i can't able to split.. its resulting in error on getting _adob itself

Comment: @robert : my error msg : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Also, its `.split()` not `.Split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var _dob = "4/10";
var _adob;
if (_dob.indexOf("/") >-1) {
    _adob = _dob.split("/");
} else {
    _adob - _dob.split("-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Direct Answer

[`indexOf(something)>-1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var _dob = "4/10";
var _adob = _dob.indexOf('/')>-1 ? _dob.split('/') : _dob.split('-');
$('#Month').val(_adob[0]);
$('#Day').val(_adob[1]);
```

### Indirectly

You really don't need to check that the string contains that... Using a regular expression, you can split on a `-`, `/`, or `.` by building a character set:

```
var _dob = '4.10';
var _aodb = _dob.split(new RegExp('[-/.]'));
```

Comment: Split should be split (*it is case sensitive and the method is with lowercase s*)

Comment: @Gaby - ty, corrected error in copy/paste section from OP...

Comment: hi i got one more similar issue in the past...thing is i want to check the specific url from youtube alone and show success status and others i want to skip by stating it as not valid url

 var _videoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhnMNwiGg5M"
                    
  if (_videoUrl.contains("youtube.com")')) {
       alert('Valid');                     
   }
   else {
       alert('Not Valid');
  }


how to check with contains similar problem for me in that too...

Comment: @unknown - `_videoUrl.indexOf('youtube.com')>-1` or `==0` to make sure its the first letters,  or `_videoUrl.match(/^youtube\.com/)` for the regexp way.